# All of my Ubuntu Apps dont work?

Tags: 12.04

All of my Ubuntu app haven't been working like the things that came with Ubuntu and the things i have downloaded from the Ubuntu software center. I cant even open things like update manager or the Ubuntu software center and all the things i need to use that i have downloaded don't work either. All it does is open up a window then closes itself imediatedly and then the "System program problem detected do you want to report the problem now?" thing come up and I've reported it many time but nothing happens still. Also a few seconds later the "The application (name of application) has closed unsuspectedly" and again I've send many error reports and if i try to reopen it, the same thing happens. please help i need the applications alot!!!!

Comment: Does a terminal open if you press ctrl + alt + T? If it does, can you try opening a program from terminal by typing for example `firefox` and pressing enter?

Comment: What where you doing when this problem occured?

Comment: **Please answer** the questions asked of you. Otherwise, there are no specifics to go on.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user
```

Comment: Do you understand OP's problem? Please explain why your answer is appropriate.